# DNSsec error in Bind9.10 following update of freebsd10.1

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, freebsd, dnssec, dmarc

My DNSsec began to fail following a ports update. I have reinstalled Bind on both master and slave but the error still persist.

```
35  ;; WE HAVE MATERIAL, WE NOW DO VALIDATION
36  ;; VERIFYING A RRset for www.ex-mailer.com. with DNSKEY:9381: success
37  ;; OK We found DNSKEY (or more) to validate the RRset
38  ;; Now, we are going to validate this DNSKEY by the DS
39  ;; ERROR no DS validates a DNSKEY in the DNSKEY RRset: FAILED
```

complete dig output  [dig output](https://bpaste.net/show/0331b459c72a)

VeriSign says I am good to go   [VeriSign diag](http://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/ex-mailer.com)

and there are no error in the bind logs.

how do I find what is causing this error and get rid of it/restore my DNSsec?

Update:
It's not stale cache. Queries from fresh remote networks obtain same results.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `dig +sigchase` output, we can see that the KSK (SEP) `DNSKEY` is:

```
ex-mailer.com.          86400   IN      DNSKEY  257 3 8 AwEAAaer0hZ5wLS++AsZyIEea+hqFzH4VKCWtFrLIUIqPU368szAfq9q 58adbqXjbizWGVimZEhVgDdUbl+TI3hQQ8eppOpX5yPr49XNv3AP6IbT pUlXAEXUjb6DsTONKciWHxo8r0Es7KL/SJSWmd3aTqtMeIrxb2SSFRmH upy034CKgrniidBv2VVI1pGsvLIDn3HYWMHqUas81iDv8EJ6c1HYiVUf w+37kfFZtj4pUmFQwwZ5yfi8pECPwLV5QImsnT3QGV2sYGP0sDWgGpz+ Sbv3+fs2u1o5AzD5nB7FeTotSdl31J0BKNpOT3gIG3JvkCaRziqqkCnL 7p+5t4+1dqE=
```

We can also see that the `DS` you found was:

```
ex-mailer.com.          85868   IN      DS      30274 8 1 9D12E47AAB1817A5062590188B7FC849FB662CE3
```

However, if I check what the `DS` should be for the above `DNSKEY` I get:

```
$ echo "ex-mailer.com.          86400   IN      DNSKEY  257 3 8 AwEAAaer0hZ5wLS++AsZyIEea+hqFzH4VKCWtFrLIUIqPU368szAfq9q 58adbqXjbizWGVimZEhVgDdUbl+TI3hQQ8eppOpX5yPr49XNv3AP6IbT pUlXAEXUjb6DsTONKciWHxo8r0Es7KL/SJSWmd3aTqtMeIrxb2SSFRmH upy034CKgrniidBv2VVI1pGsvLIDn3HYWMHqUas81iDv8EJ6c1HYiVUf w+37kfFZtj4pUmFQwwZ5yfi8pECPwLV5QImsnT3QGV2sYGP0sDWgGpz+ Sbv3+fs2u1o5AzD5nB7FeTotSdl31J0BKNpOT3gIG3JvkCaRziqqkCnL 7p+5t4+1dqE=" | dnssec-dsfromkey -1 -f - ex-mailer.com
ex-mailer.com. IN DS 47569 8 1 42665F3D9A532B16A8E5AD9564AF9936AC93F7A0
```

There's clearly a mismatch between the `DS` you looked up and the KSK currently used.

For what it's worth, I get the correct `DS` if I look it up myself:

```
$ dig @a.gtld-servers.net ex-mailer.com DS +norec +short
47569 8 1 42665F3D9A532B16A8E5AD9564AF9936AC93F7A0
```

It appears that the keys for `ex-mailer.com` may have changed in some unplanned way (not rolled over in a controlled manner) which leaves validating resolver servers in a bad state until cached data expires.

Comment: Lindqvist I am not sure if you are correct, the DS record was changed but way early yesterday. Here is a discussion on #dns where much the same was discussed.  https://bpaste.net/show/7be7bbc9d676  I guess we will see tomorrow.  I'll keep this post updated.

Comment: at this point it has been 3 days since the update and I have attempted from 3 different networks. Both TLD with registrar gkg.com and canonical domain with registrar godaddy, are having the same fail.

Comment: @nix Ok. I think you'll need to provide more details in that case. I can't reproduce the problem and what I answered was the immediately obvious problem from what you showed before.

Comment: It looks like an ISP error   http://i.imgur.com/Se0LMGC.png    and a deeper diagnostic discussion  https://bpaste.net/show/e4f1f3e4f1cb

Comment: @nix That looks like a different problem than what you asked about here...?